# Java EE RESTful Service field Injection

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly

Im having an issue deploying an application in wildfly which contains a RESTful Service that uses @Inject to inject a DAO.

THis is the error message in the logs when trying to deploy the application in wildfly:

```
Deploying /home/john/codebase/servers/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/HouseCompetitionDashboard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"HouseCompetitionDashboard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"HouseCompetitionDashboard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DAO with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.jmcdonnell.dashboard.services.PlayerService.dao
  at org.jmcdonnell.dashboard.services.PlayerService.dao(PlayerService.java:0)
"}}
```

The classes look like so:

```
@Named
public class DAO {
}



@Stateless
@Path("player")
public class PlayerService {

    @Inject
    private DAO dao;

    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void create(Player entity) {
        //dao.create(entity);
    }
}
```

Later on the DAO class will contain an Entity Manager, but for the moment it doesn't as I would at least like to get the injection working.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Named` annotaion expects some name and in name is not set - it generate default name, but, name generates in accoartinatly to camel case name of bean. You need to try specify name or either use camel case for bean name.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that about the Named Annotation/camel case requirement.

Comment: This is not true.  If I had to guess, you're actually missing a scope (assuming you don't have a `beans.xml` defined or your `beans.xml` says `annotated` for your bean type)

Comment: This shoult not to be true. But in some cases it is. I'd say this is buggy implementation, bacause in some cases I save similar problem.

Comment: There's really no use in using `@Named` when you're not using EL to reference your beans.